# Event Pattern rule "anything-but" using CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to add the following Event Pattern to specific rule on Event Bridge

```
{
  "account": ["0000000000000"],
  "source": [{
    "anything-but": ["some.source"]
  }]
}
```

I tryed to use this python code

```
event_bridge.Rule(self, "send_to_firehose",
                  event_bus=remote_eventbridge,
                  event_pattern=event_bridge.EventPattern(
                  account=[self.account],
                  source=[{"anything-but":["some.source"]}],
                  .....
```

but the "source" does not accept a json, only string array:

```
 source: typing.Optional[typing.Sequence[builtins.str]] = None,
```

So I decided to try using dumps:

```
event_bridge.Rule(self, "send_to_firehose",
                  event_bus=remote_eventbridge,
                  event_pattern=event_bridge.EventPattern(
                  account=[self.account],
                  source=[json.dumps({"anything-but":["some.source"]})],
                  .....
```

but does not work as expected, with result:

```
{
  "account": ["0000000"],
  "source": ["{\"anything-but\": [\"some.source\"]}"]
}
```

Is there any way to add "anything-but" rule in source, or this is a cdk limitation?

Comment: how did u fix the issue?

Comment: @D.B the AWS team has added this feature to the CDK a few days ago, update your cdk to the last version and this should be available

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.Match.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figure out, this is a limitation in current version of CDK.

It should be fixed with this PR from CDK Team: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/21310